# Creating a list with an else statement

Tags: java, swing, list, user-interface, if-statement

im pretty new to the java stuff, but basically im trying to add a list with and else statement, right now when i input say 01, it would appear in a gui textfield but if i input 02 it will replace 01 etc, so i want to be able to input 02, 03 etc without replacing my last input, hence only showing one thing at a time.

ive added the append, but now i get all my inputs in one line in the textarea, is possible for the inputs to be on different lines?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CreatePlaylist extends JFrame
              implements ActionListener {
    JTextField trackNo = new JTextField(2);
    TextArea playcount = new TextArea(6, 50);
    JButton play = new JButton("Play Playlist");
    JButton add = new JButton("Add Track");
    public CreatePlaylist() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 200);
        setTitle("Check Library");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.add(new JLabel("Enter Track Number:"));
        top.add(trackNo);
        top.add(add);
        top.add(play);
        play.addActionListener(this);
        add.addActionListener(this);
        add("North", top);
        JPanel middle = new JPanel();
        playcount.setText(LibraryData.listAll());
        middle.add(playcount);
        add("Center", middle);

        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == play) {
            playcount.setText(LibraryData.listAll());
        } else {
            String key = trackNo.getText();
            String name = LibraryData.getName(key);
            if (name == null) {
                playcount.setText("No such track number");
            } else {
                playcount.setText(name + " - " + LibraryData.getArtist(key));
            }           
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can append as mentioned by @Masud or get the already existing value and the new entered value and show them.

Answer (score 2):

> hence only showing one thing at a time.

Use `append` method instead of `setText`. `setText` replaces the existing text of `JTextArea`

```
 playcount.append(LibraryData.listAll());
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but nw my list deosnt center, i.e it would list in row fashion instead of column but thanks anyway.

Comment: To arrange data as column use newline `"\n"`